# clear wrapper div containing ap divs

Tags: css

Ran into a spot where I absolutely HAVE to use ap divs. The problem is: I can't find a way to clear my wrapper div. None of my tricks are working.

I wanna lose the height setting for wrapper div and still contain the ap divs.

Any ideas?

```
<pre>
<code>
#wrapper {
 position:relative;
 width:600px; 
 height:1200px; --- wanna dump this but can't find way to clear
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: #0CF;
 z-index:100;
}
#apDiv1 {
 position:absolute;
 width:200px;
 height:115px;
 z-index:1001;
 left: 89px;
 top: 329px;
 background-color: #0C0;
}
#apDiv2 {
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 z-index:1000;
 left: 383px;
 top: 36px;
 background-color: #F39;
}

div id=wrapper  
  div id=apDiv1  closediv
  div id=apDiv2 closediv  
div-- close wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing is used for floats, not absolutely positioned elements.  You cannot clear absolutely positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You have to specifiy the height of the wrapper to contain the inner absolutely positioned elements. Absolutely positioned elements don't take up any space, therefore it's impossible for the wrapper to wrap around them.

And ap divs are wonderful when used in the right context. You shouldn't "yuck" them out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can get highest child and append this highest height to parent by jQuery below

```
var t=0; // the height of the highest element (after the function runs)
var t_elem;  // the highest element (after the function runs)
$("*",elem).each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.outerHeight() > t ) {
        t_elem=this;
        t=$this.outerHeight();
        alert(t);
    }
});
```